# What does "信じて行動する" mean?

Tags: translation

Please explain more in detail and clearly that phrase "信じて行動する".

Context:

> 僕とハルはある男を信じて行動していた

Am I to understand that definition like "man of word + man of action", a person who is completely self-controlled and achieves the goals set for herself, a successful man?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The て in 信じて, means 'and then' because it is the continuous form.
It means (literal): Me and haru believed a guy and then acted(moved).

Kind of like you can say スーパーに行って、学校に戻った。I went to the supermarket and then returned to school.
The fact that you combined 信じて行動する into one thought shows that you are missing the fact that the て splits it into two separate although related thoughts.